# Infopath Form is being submitted after inserting values in People Picker/Inserting an attachment

Tags: sharepoint-addin, forms-services, infopath-rules, infopath-data-connections

My form is being submitted after inserting values in People Picker/Inserting an attachment. Why is this happening and how to prevent it? My form's behavior is not like this before, not sure why it suddenly changed.

I've already tried to delete the field and reinsert it.
I've also tried to create a new People picker field and checked if it has the same behavior, unfortunately it is still the same. So I'm not sure if this is still a infopath problem.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. Turns out the SharepointListItem_RW in my Main Data connection copies the Rule of my Button with submit action. That's why it fires when my people picker or attachment changed values.

I don't know how it suddenly copied the rules, good thing I've printed all the Rules in Rules inspector :D